# roots of a linear DE $(D^2+2cD+k)y=0$ given $c<0,k>0, c^2>k$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let y(x) be a non-trivial solution of the second order linear differential equation

$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2c\dfrac{dy}{dx}+ky=0 $$, where $c<0,k>0, c^2>k$. Then,

(a) $|y(x)|\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$

(b) $|y(x)|\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$

(c) $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}|y(x)|$ exists and is finite.

(d) none of the above

Now, solving the ODE, I get the roots as $-c\pm\sqrt{c^2-k}$.

The two roots will be real, distinct and positive and hence, option (a) should be the answer.

Did I solve this correctly ?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes : $y=e^{dx}$ so that $$ d=-c\pm\sqrt{c^2-k}$$