# follow Up question To [roots of a linear DE $(D^2+2cD+k)y=0$]

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **This is a follow Up question To [roots of a linear DE $(D^2+2cD+k)y=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243240/roots-of-a-linear-de-d22cdky-0-given-c0-k0-c2k)**

Let y(x) be a non-trivial solution of the second order linear differential equation

$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2k\dfrac{dy}{dx}+ly=0 $$
[image]

**MY approach** The charecteristic equation is $m^{2}+2km+l=0$$\Longrightarrow m=-k\pm\sqrt{k^{2}-l}$

**In Option (C)**
If $k^{2}-l<0$ $\Longrightarrow$Solution is y=$e^{-kx}\left(c_{1}cosx\left(\sqrt{l-k^{2}}\right)+c_{2}sinx\left(\sqrt{l-k^{2}}\right)\right)$$\Longrightarrow$
y$\longrightarrow0$ as x$\longrightarrow\infty$

If $k^{2}-l=0$ $\Longrightarrow$Solution is y=$\left(c_{1}+c_{2}x\right)e^{-kx}$$\Longrightarrow$y$\longrightarrow0$
as x$\longrightarrow\infty$

**Note** Some notations are changed .Do not get confuse with that
,See the question in Picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must do case work:
$$k^2-l<0$$
or
$$k^2-l=0$$
or
$$k^2-l>0$$
and the solution is given by $$y \left( x \right) ={\it \_C1}\,{{\rm e}^{ \left( -k+\sqrt {{k}^{2}-l}
 \right) x}}+{\it \_C2}\,{{\rm e}^{ \left( -k-\sqrt {{k}^{2}-l}
 \right) x}}
$$

Comment: Ok i am going to do that

Comment: additionally i have added the solution!